# using scanner input for all for loop parameters

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

Looking at this code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingMachineRevisited {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int from, to, by;
    System.out.print("Count from: ");
    from = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Count to: ");
    to = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Count by: ");
    by = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = from; i <= to; i+=by) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
}
```

This code works the way I want it to, but if i change the termination condition of the for loop to i == to, it doesnt work.

```
for (int i = from; i == to; i+=by) {
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

I would understand this is all the int's defaulted to 0 making the termination the same as the initial so the for loop would stop, but if I am initializing new values before the loop starts why doesnt it work?

Comment: When `i` gets the value `from`, it is not equal to `to` so the loop is never executed. Try your program with `from` equal to `to` and you will see that it will enter the for loop just once.

Comment: Well what are you initializing your variables to? Depending on your variables, `i+by` might just jump over the value of `to`

Comment: If i initialize them : from = 1, to = 10, by = 2. The loop wont run at all if  the termination condition is "i == to".   I realize the loop will get messed up if the inputs aren't properly entered. I am curious to why it never executes.

Comment: @Grez.Kev look at my comment to understand why. Look also at Oracle tutorial on for loop here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: I get it now. I am starting with a false statement so it never executes. Thanks Tunaki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in a `for` loop is **not** a termination condition. It's a **continuation** condition.

A `for` loop like:

```
for ( INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; UPDATE )
    STATEMENT
```

Is equivalent to

```
INITIALIZATION
while ( CONDITION ) {
    STATEMENT
    UPDATE
}
```

So the loop will continue **as long as the condition is true**, not terminate when it's true.

So when you input a `to` that's greater than your `from`, but put in the condition `i == to`, since `i` is initialized to `from`, and `from` is different than `to`, that condition will not be true, hence the loop cannot run - it only runs while it's true.

`i <= to` works because `i` starts from a lower value than `to`, and so this condition is true all the way until `i`'s value surpasses `to`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.